This error may be due to using an insufficient credential type. Try using OAuth 2.0
I try to use this API https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list
I pass just only one parameter driverID = "1M88XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
I'm sure that this is correct value because I can see my Google Drive on link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M88XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
But API is not working "and receive error "This error may be due to using an insufficient credential type. Try using OAuth 2.0"
I try to ask this question a couple of times in Google forum, but Google forum mark my question as SPAM. Very strange...
What this message means?
UPD:
Two files what require Linda. This is error I found:

This is Scopes, in this case I used wrong ID, but in previous request I used the same Scopes. In this screen I just expand scopes to make it clear.


Drive API is not a public API. It requires an authorization workflow. It seems that you are not using any authorization workflow, if yes can you share your code and details about it?

@Babanana, I use API Explorer and Turn on switch "Google OAuth 2.0". Api explorer is a right frame on Browser. On any my request I receive this error, despite I specially set this flag in API explorer. Is this a bug of Google? Or ordinary message what I need to already ignore?

I tried to replicate your issue and I am also experiencing the same thing. Even with the correct parameters. I would suggest posting here at https://issuetracker.google.com this way Google Support can directly provide answers for you.

please edit your question and include [example] we need to see how you are authorizing the request and the full request you are making.

Please note that the try me in the documentaiton does not work with all of the methods.  Please show us the code from your application that you are using.

If you check the doucmentation files.list
You will see that it requires authorization to access it

You need to be authorized to access it.  That means you need to pass an access token in the header value of the request when you use it.

I have exactly the same scope. For my wondering today my issue unexpectedly disappear. I do not changing anything in my API explorer, but error disappear.

well i cant see your code how are you authorizing it?   and where are you applying the access token.

yes, Please. Question modified with two screen for you.

you cant do that with the try me its just for testing show us your code.  the code in your application.

I remove now any AU from my application and application working fine with anonymous AUth (apikey only). Because even API explorer embedded to Chrome browser from Google get me errors (see screen above) - therefore I must refuse to use OAUTH2 in my apps. I'm sorry, I'm not kind of investigator of Google troubles, I have my own responsibility. If Google can not provide workable OAUTH2 even in own API explorer in own site and even in own browser - what does it means? This means developer must search another way to working, isn't it?
